# I am have trouble in updating node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, ubuntu

```
~$ sudo n stable 
   installed : v12.16.1 (with npm 6.13.4)
~$ node --version 
v0.10.31
~$ npm --version 
1.4.23
```

I updated node through the terminal, but i am not sure whether it has been updated or not?

Comment: What is `n`? Nvm?

Comment: @cubrr No, It's just another Node.js version management. https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Comment: It's because you installed `n` as `sudo`, but your node is still point to your home path. If you enter `sudo node --version`, you probably see new version.